# ON_CALL AND EXPECT_CALL on same method with different parameter matchers generates saturated and active error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

In this example bellow I will obtain the following behavior:

*EXPECT_CALL(barMock, doBar(7))...
Expected arg #0: is equal to 7
Actual: 5
Expected: to be called once
Actual: called once - saturated and active*

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual bool doBar(int barParam) = 0;
};

class BarMock : public IBar
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(doBar, bool(int));
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(IBar& bar_)
        : bar{ &bar_ }
    {

    }
    void doFoo()
    {
        bar->doBar(7);
        bar->doBar(5);
    }
    IBar* bar;
};

class FooBarTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        ON_CALL(barMock, doBar(testing::_)).WillByDefault(testing::Return(true));
    }

    testing::NiceMock<BarMock> barMock;
};

TEST_F(FooBarTest, OnCallExpectCallSameMethod)
{

    Foo               foo(barMock);

    ON_CALL(barMock, doBar(5)).WillByDefault(testing::Return(true));
    EXPECT_CALL(barMock, doBar(7)).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));

    foo.doFoo();

}
```

Google test versions tested:

- 1.8.0
- 1.8.1

---

1. Is this intended to cause an error?
2. How does google test sets the
   order calls? Does EXPECT_CALL has higher priority only in this
   scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is intended to be an error. One of the GoogleMock policies is that in case of possible ambiguity it's better to throw an error an make user state his intention explicitly.

Adding `EXPECT_CALL` macro effectively says "I care about calls of this method". Whenever `EXPECT_CALL` is set, GoogleMock will try to match every `EXPECT_CALL` it has seen in reverse order of declaration (so the latest defined expects are matched first).
One of the reasons for this design is to allow overriding less specific expects with more specific ones (e.g. in constructor of test fixture you set less restrictive expects, but for certain tests you want to match more precisely). [Documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#using-multiple-expectations-multiexpectations).

However, there is a way of "ignoring" already fulfilled expectations by adding [`.RetiresOnSaturation()`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#controlling-when-an-expectation-retires)

```
TEST_F(FooBarTest, OnCallExpectCallSameMethod)
{
    Foo foo(barMock);
    ON_CALL(barMock, doBar(5)).WillByDefault(testing::Return(true));
    EXPECT_CALL(barMock, doBar(7))
        .WillOnce(testing::Return(true))
        .RetiresOnSaturation();

    foo.doFoo();
}
```

`RetiresOnSaturation()` will make expectations retired after it has been saturated (i.e. called as many time as expected). GoogleMock will skip over retired expectations as long as there are still any non-retired ones (if all of them are retired then it still prints an error).

---

If you however need to accept calls `doBar(5)` *before* `doBar(7)`, then the only way to do so is to define it as expectation as well:

```
TEST_F(FooBarTest, OnCallExpectCallSameMethod)
{
    Foo foo(barMock);
    EXPECT_CALL(barMock, doBar(5)).WillRepeatedly(testing::Return(true));
    EXPECT_CALL(barMock, doBar(7))
        .WillOnce(testing::Return(true))
        .RetiresOnSaturation();

    foo.doFoo();
}
```

`RetiresOnSaturation()` is still needed because of LIFO (last in, first out) processing of expectations.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tested the OnCalExpectSameMethod and remove the RetiresOnSaturation. The test passes. If I replace the first expect_call with an on_call the test fails. Could you please clarify why this happens when you combine expect_call and on_call on the same function, even if the functions can be identified by different parameters.

Comment: @AlexDamian I always assumed that EXPECT_CALLs are considered only if there are none EXPECT_CALL defined later than this one (or they are inactive), and ON_CALL is considered to be the defined before any EXPECT_CALL (so last to be checked in the queue). It also fails as expected in my tests (without RetiresOnSaturation). I suppose it may have been changed in newer googlemock?